# splash screen that can make a user to wait as the program initializes in IONIC 2

Tags: ionic2, screen, ionic3, splash-screen

What is the easiest way i can make a splash screen that can make a user to wait as the program initializes in IONIC 2. Its taking abnormally long with a white screen.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the splash screeDelay time in config.xml so splash screen will display for long time. Also see the other important properties below.

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
```

Refer this [link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/) for property definitions.

> 1. SplashScreenDelay (number, default to 3000). Amount of time in milliseconds to wait before automatically hide splash screen.
> 2. "SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" preference is also optional and defaults to true. When set to true splash screen will only appear on
>      application launch. However, if you plan to use
>      navigator.app.exitApp() to close application and force splash screen
>      appear on next launch, you should set this property to false (this
>      also applies to closing the App with Back button).
> 3. FadeSplashScreenDuration (float, defaults to 500): Specifies the number of milliseconds for the splash screen fade effect to execute.
> 4. FadeSplashScreen (boolean, defaults to true): Set to false to prevent the splash screen from fading in and out when its display
>      state changes.
> 5. ShowSplashScreenSpinner (boolean, defaults to true): Set to false to hide the splash-screen spinner.

On the first page of launch, you can put splashScreen.hide() to hide the splash screen manually.

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if(this.platform.is('cordova')  || this.platform.is('android')){
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      }
    }, 300);
```

Production Ionic builds will take only 2 to 3 seconds to launch please check the configurations if it took more that

Comment: It works but with the default splash screen, I was thinking something like a moving image to keep the user busy as the program loads

Comment: refer this link for animated splash screen https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-animated-splash-screen-in-ionic/ . If your App do some HTTP requests on App launch, build a intermediate page with some animation or message till the HTTP requests get complete. Without any HTTP requests your App is expected to launch in 2 to 3 seconds in production which is not long wait.